# Creating a mongo database in android

Tags: android, mongodb

Is it possible to create a mongo database in android? I ve been doing some research but all i ve found out is that it is simple to connect to a db, but not how to actually create it.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a mongo database in Android"? Do you mean have the database running on the device itself or have the database running on a server and have an Android app connect to it?

Comment: I ve been watching some tutorials and it shows creating a database with sqllite. Can i create it like that with mongo?

Comment: SQLite is a lightweight database that's generally on the device itself. Generally you wouldn't *want* to have a MongoDB database on the device itself even if you could.

Comment: Thank you, guess im gonna just connect to the database.

Comment: Probably makes more sense - SQLite is specifically designed to be "lightweight" so it's suitable for more resource-constrained environments like phones, but MongoDB can be fairly resource-intensive.

Answer (score 0):

If you're considering a local database you can use:
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/android/#std-label-android-intro
It allow to use a non relational local mongo database that can be very useful in some scenarios.

It can also be used to connecting to an existing mongo database on a server